# How to retrieve host, port, sid, user and password informations in java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have an Oracle connection (in a java.sql.Connection object) that is mounted from a properties file (ApplicationResources.properties).

How do I capture information about host, port, sid, user and password? (I need this information to call a specific database function through my java application)

Below my code:

```
private void conectaBanco() {
    ServiceLocator sl = new ServiceLocator();
    InitialContext ic = null;
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        if (conn == null) {
            ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup(sl.getInfo().getString("JNDI"));                
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit( true );
                            
            // I need host, port, sid and password information
            System.out.println("USER " + conn.getMetaData().getUserName());                                                
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao tentar abrir conexao com o banco de dados.", e);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao tentar abrir conexao com o banco de dados.", e);
    }
    
    if(conn != null)
        rastrear.definePredicate(conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem adding on my Weblogic configuration JDBC the additional parameters (host, user, port, sid - the password is returned automaticaly).
And I got this values throw this code below:

```
import weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection;
import java.util.Properties;
(...)
public Properties retornaPropriedadesConexao(){
    PoolConnection pc = (PoolConnection)conn;
    Properties p = pc.getConnectionEnv().getDriverProperties();                            
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SESSION SID:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;
```

ORACLE_SID:

```
SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;
```

HOST (Database machine) :

```
SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name FROM dual;
```

Password: See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_password_storage.htm

CLIENT SIDE Port:

```
Select port from v$session;
```

SERVER OS PID of Oracle server process connected to client process

```
SELECT p.spid
FROM   v$process p, v$session s
WHERE s.paddr = p.addr and 
sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') = s.sid;
```

Server side port:

This is really difficult since the server process port is mapped to a different port then the initial - for example port 12102 in listener.ora/tnsnames.ora get mapped by listener to a arbitrary free one (by the way: thats the reason why often firewalls need to be shutdown and while connections cannot get after mapping through firewall. This can be fixed but this is another story)

Below code

- grants required privileges
- defines a java stored function "Util.RunThis" which executes on database server a OS command passed into function and return string.
- "Util.RunThis" is mapped to PL/SQL function "RUN_CMD"
- "GET_PORT" is a PL/SQL function returning a numeric value of the used Port of the database server process connected to client session. Inside GET_PORT the SELECT is used to determine database server process pid replacing [SPID] in command below

  ```
    /usr/sbin/lsof -Pan -p [SPID] -i
  ```
- finally invoking a simple select we get the Port of database server process attached to current session

  ```
    connect / as sysdba

    grant select on sys.v_$process to scott;        
    grant select on sys.v_$session to scott;

    begin
      dbms_java.grant_permission
          ('SCOTT',
           'SYS:java.io.FilePermission',
           '<<ALL FILES>>',
           'execute'); 
    end;
    /

    connect scott/tiger@foo.com

    create or replace and compile java source named "Util"
    as
     import java.io.*;
     import java.lang.*;
     import java.nio.charset.Charset;
     import java.nio.*;
     public class Util extends Object
     {
       public static String RunThis(String args)
       {
         Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
         String rc = args;

         try
         {

           Process p = rt.exec(args);

           int bufSize = 4096;
           BufferedInputStream bis =
           new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream(), bufSize);
           int len;
           byte buffer[] = new byte[bufSize];

           // Echo back what the program spit out
           while ((len = bis.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) != -1)
           {
             String xxx = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
             rc = rc + xxx;
           }
           p.waitFor();

           rc = rc + "ABC";

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           e.printStackTrace();
           rc = "Exception!!!" ;
         }

         finally
         {
           return rc;
         }
       }
     }
    /

    create or replace function RUN_CMD( p_cmd in varchar2) return VARCHAR2
    as language java
    name 'Util.RunThis(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
    /

    create or replace function GET_PORT return number
    as
      SPID NUMBER;
      retval varchar2(32000);
      y varchar2(1024);
      cmd VARCHAR2(256);
    begin
      SELECT 
        p.spid 
      INTO 
        SPID
      FROM   
        sys.v_$process p, 
        sys.v_$session s
      WHERE 
        s.paddr = p.addr and 
        sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') = s.sid;

      cmd :=  '/usr/sbin/lsof -Pan -p [SPID] -i';

      /* raw string data returned from Shell executing cmd */
      retval := run_cmd(replace(cmd,'[SPID]', SPID));

      /* get last occurance of : marking redirected port */
      y := substr(retval,INSTR(retval,':', -1)+1,1024);

      /* return the numeric port by stripping info like " (ESTABLISHED)" */
      return to_number(substr(y,1,INSTR(y, ' ')-1));
    end;
    /
    show errors

    select get_port from dual;

    /*-------------------- OUTPUT -------------------------- */

    SQL> connect / as sysdba

    grant select on sys.v_$process to scott;

    grant select on sys.v_$session to scott;

    begin
      dbms_java.grant_permission
          ('SCOTT',
           'SYS:java.io.FilePermission',
           '<<ALL FILES>>',
           'execute');
    end;
    /Connected.
    SQL> SQL>
    Grant succeeded.

    SQL> SQL>
    Grant succeeded.

    SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

    SQL> connect scott/tiger@foo.com

    Connected.
    SQL> create or replace and compile java source named "Util"
      2  as
     import java.io.*;
     import java.lang.*;
     import java.nio.charset.Charset;
      3    4    5    6   import java.nio.*;
      7   public class Util extends Object
      8   {
      9     public static String RunThis(String args)
       {
         Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     10   11   12       String rc = args;
     13
     14       try
     15       {
     16
     17         Process p = rt.exec(args);

     18   19         int bufSize = 4096;
     20         BufferedInputStream bis =
     21         new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream(), bufSize);
     22         int len;
           byte buffer[] = new byte[bufSize];
     23   24
           // Echo back what the program spit out
           while ((len = bis.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) != -1)
     25   26   27         {
     28           String xxx = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
     29           rc = rc + xxx;
     30         }
           p.waitFor();
     31   32
           rc = rc + "ABC";

     33   34   35       }
     36       catch (Exception e)
     37       {
     38         e.printStackTrace();
     39         rc = "Exception!!!" ;
     40       }
     41
     42       finally
     43       {
     44         return rc;
     45       }
       }
     46   47   }
    / 48

    Java created.

    SQL> create or replace function RUN_CMD( p_cmd in varchar2) return VARCHAR2
    as language java
    name 'Util.RunThis(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
    /  2    3    4

    Function created.

    SQL> create or replace function GET_PORT return number
    as
      SPID NUMBER;
      retval varchar2(32000);
      2    3    4    5    y varchar2(1024);
      cmd VARCHAR2(256);
    begin
      6    7    8    SELECT
        p.spid
      INTO
      9   10   11      SPID
      FROM
        sys.v_$process p,
        sys.v_$session s
      WHERE
     12   13   14   15   16      s.paddr = p.addr and
        sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') = s.sid;

      cmd :=  '/usr/sbin/lsof -Pan -p [SPID] -i';

     17   18   19   20   21    /* raw string data returned from Shell executing cmd */
      retval := run_cmd(replace(cmd,'[SPID]', SPID));

     22   23   24    /* get last occurance of : marking redirected port */
      y := substr(retval,INSTR(retval,':', -1)+1,1024);

      /* return the numeric port by stripping info like " (ESTABLISHED)" */
     25   26   27   28    return to_number(substr(y,1,INSTR(y, ' ')-1));
    end;
    /
    show errors 29   30
    Function created.

    SQL>
    No errors.
    SQL> select get_port from dual;

      GET_PORT
    ----------
         36586
  ```